# Scala- JSON HTTP Post request throwing errors

Tags: java, json, apache, scala

I have some scala code, which dealing with http post request.
The below mentioned is the sample code,

```
import java.io._
import org.apache.commons._
import org.apache.http._
import org.apache.http.client._
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import java.util.ArrayList
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity
import com.google.gson.Gson

case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)

object HttpJsonPostTest extends App {

  // create our object as a json string
  val spock = new Person("I love java")
  val spockAsJson = new Gson().toJson(spock)

  // add name value pairs to a post object
  val post = new HttpPost("http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson")
  val nameValuePairs = new ArrayList[NameValuePair]()

  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JSON", spockAsJson))
  post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs))

  // send the post request
  val client = new DefaultHttpClient
  val response = client.execute(post)

  println("--- HEADERS ---")
  response.getAllHeaders.foreach(arg => println(arg))
}
```

`ERROR:While running this application, it is showing "Project sample contain build errors, Continue launch? "`

in Console: `Error: Could not find or load main class sample.HttpJsonPostTest`

Please anybody assist me on the same would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Reddi Babu

Comment: How are you trying to run it? Maven, sbt, triggering jvm with command line?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile, you have this case class:

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int)
```

And lather in the process you're instantiating a new `Person` without specifying all the parameters:

```
val spock = new Person("I love java")
```

You need either to add all the parameters:

```
val spock = Person("I love java", "some lastname", 18)
```

Or specify defaults in the case class:

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String = "some last name", age: Int = 18)
```

After fixing this errors I got this response:

```
--- HEADERS ---
Date: Mon, 19 May 2014 09:47:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 0
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,80:quic
```

Also note that the `new` for case classes is not necessary.